# Get the final destination after WP_Http redirects (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm doing some requests to an API via WordPress, and the API uses SSL connections if they're turned on in the API settings. I'd like to determine whether SSL is turned on or off without having to ask the user if SSL is turned on on their account, and the API does a good job at redirecting, meaning

- If I access http://api/endpoint and SSL is turned on, I'm redirected to https://api/endpoint
- If I access https://api/endpoint and SSL is turned off, I'm redirected to http://api/endpoint

Now what I'd like to do is see whether a redirect happened or not and record that to my options so that the other requests are fired to the correct URL without any redirections.

So my question is: is there a way to determine the final destination after firing a `WP_Http->request()` when the request is being redirected?

I can't see any info about that in the response arrays, I only get to see the final response but I have no idea what URL that came from. What I can do is set the `redirection` parameter to 0 and catch the max redirects allowed error, but that's not bullet-proof, since I still don't know whether the redirect happened from http to https or simply another page under http.

I hope this all makes sense, let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks!

~ K

Answer (score 1):

check $response['headers'] - they may contain 'location' key.

It all depends on the HTTP library you are using.
See class-http.php(wp 3.0.1) file:
line 1393, http_api_curl action - curl handle available directly to catch anything.

fopen:
check lines 887-888, and $http_response_header variable.

also, try to override processHeaders function as it has an access to raw http headers.

Answer (score 0):

The WP_Http class processes the headers and removes all but the last one. So you could do what jetdog described above. Check the original URL and compare it to the returned $response['headers']['location']. If it is different, than you know it redirected.

Comment: The problem is that there is no `$response['header']['location']` for certain transports used by WP_Http.